# How to set mlflow version field

Tags: python, mlflow

I just started to work with `mlflow` (`1.24.0`)

How can I set (update) the version field ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The version field is "Commit hash of the executed code, if in a git repository." If you want to set it, you need to set System tags mlflow.source.git.commit to version you want when you start a run  e.g. `with mlflow.start_run(tags={"mlflow.source.git.commit": <version>})` . Unfortunately the version column in MLflow UI display only strings with maximum 6 signs, longer string are cutting to lengths of six. If you want to set another value than commit hash you should use tags with your own name e.g. `with mlflow.start_run(tags={"version": <version>})`, that show you in column Tags.